# splitting a string into multiple variables

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to split a string into data to be stored into multiple variables.  my string consists of data separated by a different(random) number of spaces.

```
"Mike Smith           123     23          33   2 1"
```

I have tried using the string.split method however I am having problems storing the numeric data.

```
Dim strUserInfo As String
    Dim strFirstName, strLastName As String
    Dim intAvg, intHcp, intTotalPins, intGamesTracked As Integer
    strUserInfo = lstUsers.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim strarr() As String
    strarr = strUserInfo.Split("."c)
    strFirstName = strarr(0)
    strLastName = strarr(1)
```

Comment: `I am having problems storing the numeric data.` Would you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how many spaces are between each section, you might want to use this overload of [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
strarr = strUserInfo.split(New Char() { " "c }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

And when you want to store the in an `Integer` variable, use [`CInt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) (or [`Integer.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), like this:

```
strFirstName = strarr(0)
strLastName = strarr(1)
intAvg = CInt(strarr(2))
intHcp = CInt(strarr(3))
intTotalPins = CInt(strarr(4))
intGamesTracked = CInt(strarr(5))
```

Comment: Thank you, the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries method worked great

Answer (score 0):

Another way to parse it is using regular expressions:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim input As String = "Mike Smith           123     23          33   2 1"
Dim matches = Regex.Matches(input, "\w+")
Dim output = (From match As Match In matches Select match.Value).ToArray
```